# How do I use the Facebook API to autologin to a specific account

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

So I am working for a hosting company and we are looking for ways to make our support much simpler. Most of our clients contact us through facebook instead of our helpdesk software.
How can I use the Facebook API so that when our staff login to our helpdesk they can gain access to the facebook messages on the specific account without needing to login to the account(as in them having to type in the email/username and password).
Of course the email account and password is required, but are there parameters that I can set in a php script(Email, Password) that can log straight into the facebook account. And then the API can pass the information such as the Inbox from the account so we can view our clients messages without the staff needing to know the email or pass.

Answer (score 1):

No - there is no supported method of logging in like this. If Facebook catches you attempting to use their service like this you will most likely be blocked. Since you use your Facebook accounts for customer interactions, this would be very much unwanted.

What you can try do is using the Facebook API to read the inbox of a specific user. For this you'll need to user account to grant you the [`read_mailbox` permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/) and then you can make requests to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USERID/inbox
```

This will return a list of messages and their participants. After you have the id of a specific message, you can query the API with it directly:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/message_id
```

This will give you data on the entire thread of messages attached to that id. From here you can integrate the data into your own applications however you see fit.

Comment: So that would mean Zendesk for Facebook is bad as they have integration with what I want but they charge monthly. Link: http://www.zendesk.com/product/features/facebook

Comment: @JoshuaBlanch - I've never used it - so I don't know... Does it ask you to enter a Facebook username and password?